# If $X$ has the discrete topology then the Stone-Čech compactification is zero dimensional.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $X$ has the discrete topology then the Stone-Čech compactification is zero-dimensional.

I would like to show the above to be true. If I can show that every closure (in $\beta X$) of an open set (in $\beta X$) is open (in $\beta X$), then I would be done.

Here zero-dimensional means that the continuous simple functions on $\beta X$ are dense in  $\beta X$.

Comment: Overkill proof: $\beta(X) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_2^X)$ is zero-dimensional since in a boolean ring every prime ideal is maximal.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Martin. I am unfamiliar with Spec$(\mathbb{F}_{2}^{X})$. If this is fairly easily explained, and the isomorphism is too, then I would be appreciated to hear it. I would also be interested in seeing a possibly less involved way if you have one to hand!

Comment: As a reference, see Theorem 2.85 in "C.D. Aliprantis and K.C. Border, Infinite Dimensional Analysis, 3rd edition, 2006"

Answer (score 4):

The fact is a simple observation. I use the construction of $\beta X$ by zero sets of $X$.

Let $X$ be an infinite discrete space. Consider $\mathcal{P}(X)$ -- the algebra of all subsets of $X$. It is easy to see that $Stone(\mathcal{P}(X))$ is $\beta X$ (so $\beta X$ must be zero-dimensional as the Stone space of every Boolean algebra is). Indeed, every subset of a discrete space is a zero set, hence $\mathcal{P}(X)=\mathcal{Z}(X)$ (zero sets of $X$), so ultrafilters in $\mathcal{Z}(X)$ are the same as ultrafilters of algebra $\mathcal{P}(X)$, and a basic set $U_A=\{p: A\in p\}$ of the Stone space is a basic set $U_{X\setminus A}=\{p: X\setminus A\not\in p\}$ of the topology of $\beta X$. As $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, $X\setminus A$ is also an arbitrary subset of $X$, thus those two bases are equal.